# React click button event on list always returns reference to the last element

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, jsx

I'm trying to recover the selected item on array of elements, I have an API service which returns a list of 5 jobs and a page on React to display the applicants. The rendered table from the list has a menu button for each row, when I click on the menu button it fires the handleMenuOpen event and returns the index of the selected job, but when the See applicants menuItem is clicked the handleSeeApplicantsClick event is fired and the returned value is always 4 (the index of the last job) can you please help me with this?

Thanks in advance

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

import ApiService from '../../services/ApiService';

export default function Evaluation(props) {
    const [jobs, setJobs] = useState([]);
    const [selected, setSelected] = useState(null);
    const [anchorEl, setAnchorEl] = useState(null);

    const columns = [
        {label: 'Description', minWidth: 220, width: 200,},
        {label: '', minWidth: 20, width: 20},
    ];

    const loadJobs = async() => {
        const result = await ApiService.get('/u/jobs');
        setJobs(result.data || []);
    };

    const loadSelectedJob = async(jobId) => {
        const result = await ApiService.get('/u/job/'+jobId);
        setSelected(result);
    };

    useEffect( async() => {
        if(!jobs?.length) loadJobs();
    }, []);

    const handleSeeApplicantsClick = (i) => {
        console.log(i);
        setAnchorEl(null);
    };

    const handleMenuOpen = (e, i) => {
        console.log(i);
        setAnchorEl(e?.currentTarget);
    }

    return (<div>
        <TableContainer component={Paper}>
            <Table stickyHeader>
                <TableHead>
                    <TableRow>
                        { columns.map((x, i) => <TableCell key={i}>{ x.label }</TableCell>) }
                    </TableRow>
                </TableHead>
                <TableBody>
                    {jobs.map( (x, j) => <TableRow key={x.id} >
                        <TableCell>
                            <Typography variant="body2">{ x.description }</Typography>
                        </TableCell>
                        <TableCell>
                            <IconButton onClick={ (e) => handleMenuOpen(e, i) }>
                                <MenuIcon />
                            </IconButton>
                            <Menu anchorEl={anchorEl} open={ Boolean(anchorEl) } onClose={() => handleMenuOpen(null)}>
                                <MenuItem onClick={ (ex) => { handleSeeApplicantsClick(i) }}>See applicants</MenuItem>
                            </Menu>
                        </TableCell>
                    </TableRow> )}
                </TableBody>
            </Table>
        </TableContainer>
    </div>);
}
```

**Edit:**
As suggested I've changed the code like this

```
 <IconButton onClick={ (e) => handleMenuOpen(e, j) }>
                                <MenuIcon />
                            </IconButton>
```

But it does not fix the error, the last index is always returned.

Answer (score 0):

Change `handleMenuOpen(e, i)` to `handleMenuOpen(e, j)`

`i` is the final value of your previous `columns.map(x, i)` whereas you are rendering using `jobs.map( (x, j))`

Comment: I've changed the variable but still returns 4

Answer (score 0):

change `<IconButton onClick={ (e) => handleMenuOpen(e, i) }>` to `<IconButton onClick={ (e) => handleMenuOpen(e, j) }>`

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: Sorry, I've changed that variable but the error persists.

Answer (score 0):

change the function param  `<IconButton onClick={ (e) => handleMenuOpen(e, i) }>`

to  `<IconButton onClick={ (e) => handleMenuOpen(e, j) }>` because in map index value is setting into j, you need to access from j, in your example...

```
 <TableBody>
                    {jobs.map( (x, j) => <TableRow key={x.id} >
                        <TableCell>
                            <Typography variant="body2">{ x.description }</Typography>
                        </TableCell>
                        <TableCell>
                            <IconButton onClick={ (e) => handleMenuOpen(e, i) }>
                                <MenuIcon />
                            </IconButton>
                            <Menu anchorEl={anchorEl} open={ Boolean(anchorEl) } onClose={() => handleMenuOpen(null)}>
                                <MenuItem onClick={ (ex) => { handleSeeApplicantsClick(i) }}>See applicants</MenuItem>
                            </Menu>
                        </TableCell>
                    </TableRow> )}
                </TableBody>

or for best approch you can handle this through by your unique id {x.id} if its unique
```